# Forcibly install a package, despite missing dependency?

Tags: solaris

In Solaris (11.3), is it possible to **forcibly install** a package from a repository (the Solaris repository), despite that one of the requirements is missing?

Alternatively - since another (newer) version of the package exists and has been installed - is there some way to "trick" pkg into accepting the existing package?

As a third option, would it be possible to install a (empty) dummy-package with the correct name and version?  If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

There is no "force" or "ignore dependency" option in IPS.

If the newer version has the exact same package name, but a newer version number, then IPS should accept that as satisfying the dependency.   Otherwise you could, as you suggested, make an empty package with the correct name and version number and install that, or make your own version of the package you're trying to install without listing the dependency.

But if the package is in the Solaris repository, the dependency should be there too, so why not just install the dependency?